# How do I make a Rigidbody 2D move in the direction the user swiped in?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mobile, scripting, game-physics

Using Unity 2D and c#, I'm trying to make it so that a gameobject in a mobile game will move continuously and smoothly in the direction the user swiped in. The code below is what I've been trying to get to work and whenever I run it, nothing happens. The gameobject just stays in place whenever I swipe. I'm pretty new to this kind of stuff so I'm having trouble finding out what the problem is. I think it has something to do with the if and else statements from lines 38 to 62, but I'm not entirely sure. Thank you so much for your help.

```
private Vector3 fp;   //First touch position
private Vector3 lp;   //Last touch position

private float dragDistance;  //minimum distance for a swipe to be registered
private float speed = 10;

private Rigidbody2D rb;
private Vector2 moveVelocity;

void Start() {
    dragDistance = Screen.height * 5 / 100; //dragDistance is 5% height of the screen
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}

void Update() {

    if (Input.touchCount == 1) // user is touching the screen with a single touch
    {
        Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0); // get the touch
        if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began) //check for the first touch
        {
            fp = touch.position;
            lp = touch.position;
        }
        else if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved) // update the last position based on where they moved
        {
            lp = touch.position;
        }
        else if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended) //check if the finger is removed from the screen
        {
            lp = touch.position;  //last touch position. Ommitted if you use list

            //Check if drag distance is greater than ?% of the screen height
            if (Mathf.Abs(lp.x - fp.x) > dragDistance || Mathf.Abs(lp.y - fp.y) > dragDistance)
            {//It's a drag
             //check if the drag is vertical or horizontal

                if (Mathf.Abs(lp.x - fp.x) > Mathf.Abs(lp.y - fp.y))
                {   //If the horizontal movement is greater than the vertical movement...
                    if ((lp.x > fp.x))  //If the movement was to the right)
                    {   //Right swipe
                        Vector2 moveInput = new Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"));
                        moveVelocity = moveInput.normalized * speed;
                    }
                    else
                    {   //Left swipe
                        Vector2 moveInput = new Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"));
                        moveVelocity = moveInput.normalized * speed;
                    }
                }
                else
                {   //the vertical movement is greater than the horizontal movement
                    if (lp.y > fp.y)  //If the movement was up
                    {   //Up swipe
                        Vector2 moveInput = new Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"));
                        moveVelocity = moveInput.normalized * speed;
                    }
                    else
                    {   //Down swipe
                        Vector2 moveInput = new Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"));
                        moveVelocity = moveInput.normalized * speed;
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }

}

void FixedUpdate() {
    rb.MovePosition(rb.position + moveVelocity * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all all your cases are exactly equal:

```c#
if (Mathf.Abs(lp.x - fp.x) > Mathf.Abs(lp.y - fp.y))
{   //If the horizontal movement is greater than the vertical movement...
    if ((lp.x > fp.x))  //If the movement was to the right)
    {   //Right swipe
        Vector2 moveInput = new Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"));
        moveVelocity = moveInput.normalized * speed;
    }
    else
    {   //Left swipe
        Vector2 moveInput = new Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"));
        moveVelocity = moveInput.normalized * speed;
    }
}
else
{   //the vertical movement is greater than the horizontal movement
    if (lp.y > fp.y)  //If the movement was up
    {   //Up swipe
        Vector2 moveInput = new Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"));
        moveVelocity = moveInput.normalized * speed;
    }
    else
    {   //Down swipe
        Vector2 moveInput = new Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"));
        moveVelocity = moveInput.normalized * speed;
    }
}
```

They all use the exact same two lines

```c#
Vector2 moveInput = new Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"));
moveVelocity = moveInput.normalized * speed;
```

---

My guess is that `Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal")` and `Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical")` are simply always `0` and therefore no movement happens at all. As far as I know it only works for Keyboard and mouse input, not for touches.

Wouldn't you rather according to your swipe direction rather do e.g.

```c#
if (Mathf.Abs(lp.x - fp.x) > Mathf.Abs(lp.y - fp.y))
{   
    //If the horizontal movement is greater than the vertical movement...
    if (lp.x > fp.x)  //If the movement was to the right)
    {   //Right swipe
        moveVelocity = Vector2.right;
    }
    else
    {   //Left swipe
        moveVelocity = Vector2.left;
    }
}
else
{   //the vertical movement is greater than the horizontal movement
    if (lp.y > fp.y)  //If the movement was up
    {   //Up swipe
        moveVelocity = Vector2.up;
    }
    else
    {   //Down swipe
        moveVelocity = Vector2.down;
    }
}
```

And then

```c#
void FixedUpdate() 
{
    rb.MovePosition(rb.position + moveVelocity * speed * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

Note that instead of [`Time.fixedDeltaTime`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-fixedDeltaTime.html)

> For reading the delta time it is recommended to use `Time.deltaTime` instead because it automatically returns the right delta time if you are inside a `FixedUpdate` function or `Update` function.

---

Alternatively you could btw also directly assign the [`rb.velocity`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D-velocity.html)

```c#
if (Mathf.Abs(lp.x - fp.x) > Mathf.Abs(lp.y - fp.y))
{   
    //If the horizontal movement is greater than the vertical movement...
    if (lp.x > fp.x)  //If the movement was to the right)
    {   //Right swipe
        rb.velocity = Vector2.right * speed;
    }
    else
    {   //Left swipe
        rb.velocity = Vector2.left * speed;;
    }
}
else
{   //the vertical movement is greater than the horizontal movement
    if (lp.y > fp.y)  //If the movement was up
    {   //Up swipe
        rb.velocity = Vector2.up * speed;;
    }
    else
    {   //Down swipe
        rb.velocity = Vector2.down * speed;;
    }
}
```

without having `FixedUpdate`. Since you here only change the `velocity` of the Rigidbody and don't move it directly it is ok to do this in `Update`.

---

General notes:

You should use a `switch-case` instead for

```c#
switch(touch.phase)
{
    case TouchPhase.Began:
        fp = touch.position;
        // No need to assign lp here actually
        // lp = touch.position;
        break;

    case TouchPhase.Ended:
        // lp could actually be a local variable - no need to make it a field
        var lp = touch.position;
        ...

        break;
}
```

Since you don't use the `lp` value assigned in the `TouchPhase.Moved` anyway you could actually completely skip this block.

You could make your `if-else` checks for the moved direction a bit more readable / better to maintain by introducing one additional variable:

```c#
var lp = touch.position;
var difference = lp - fp;

if (difference.x > dragDistance || difference.y > dragDistance)
{
    if (Mathf.Abs(difference.x) > Mathf.Abs(difference.y))
    {
        if (difference.x > 0)
        {
            // Right swipe
        }
        else
        {   
            // Left swipe
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (difference.y > 0)
        {
            // Up swipe
        }
        else
        {   
            // Down swipe
        }
    }
}
```